# table sorting and filtering in javafx giving repititive results while adding new value to observable list

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I followed [this](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/) tutorial in my application, but when i am adding a new value to the masterData ObservableList, table shows me repetitive values. If i use `table.getItems().clear()` method to remove previous entry from the table it throws an unsupported method exception. I tried removing the sortedData but still getting the same exception. I tried calling the `table.setItems(sortedData)` conditionally but once this is executed, again i get to the same exception. Any way to handle this ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You get the exception because you are modifying the sorted/filtered list with `table.getItems().clear()` instead of modifying the underlying list (i.e. `masterData.clear()`). That's not the problem though. If you are seeing duplicate entries in the table, something is wrong with your code (the tutorial code does not produce duplicates). No-one can possibly tell you what is wrong with your code without seeing it: [edit] your question to include a [MCVE].

Comment: Solved thank you very much.....

Comment: How? Can you explain what was wrong?

Comment: I was trying to modify sortedList which is unmodifiable , i created another ObservableList and mirrored it to masterData then passed that observable list in FilteredList and it is working fine...

Comment: That just sounds like a big hack though. You shouldn't need to do any of that: you should just add a new value to `masterData` and it will all work.